# How to prevent Octave from summing row and column vectors?

Tags: octave

In Octave, in general, '`+`' will only work when the two operands have the same dimension.

There seems to be an exception to this rule: if you '`+`' a row vector (`1 x n`) and a column vector (`n x 1`), Octave will produce a (reasonable) Matrix of dimensions (`n x n`):

```
>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a =

   1   2   3   4   5

>> b = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
b =

   1
   2
   3
   4
   5

>> a+b
ans =

    2    3    4    5    6
    3    4    5    6    7
    4    5    6    7    8
    5    6    7    8    9
    6    7    8    9   10
```

Can this be prevented, or at least be made to generate a warning? It seems potentially unsafe; I was recently bitten by a bug that was being masked by this behaviour.

Thanks!

Comment: Masked? If an array is nxn instead of 1xn, that’s a pretty big difference.

Comment: Yes, perhaps it wasn't the best term - I meant that this wrong result was being returned by a function and causing havoc elsewhere (due to the wrong dimensions), so I had to invest some time in tracing the issue back to the place where I was mistakenly summing row and column vectors. No biggie, and probably just a rookie mistake I guess. But it did lead me to think "I wonder if I can prevent this from happening again somehow".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this cannot be prevented. You need to check the input of your functions. The exception you mention is not an exception, it's the language syntax.

Element-wise operations require that dimensions have dimensions of equal lengths or length of one.  The feature you are trying to prevent is also the feature that makes this work:

```
octave:1> a = 1:4
a =

   1   2   3   4

octave:2> a+1
ans =

   2   3   4   5

octave:3> a == 2
ans =

  0  1  0  0
```

In the above examples, the value in the dimension with length 1 (1x1) is broadcasted or expanded. This feature is named Broadcasting in Octave and Python, and Implicit Expansion in Matlab. There's a bunch of operators and functions, such as `==` and `max` which also broadcast.

For a while, in Octave 3.6 and 3.8, it was possible to disable this by turning the `Octave:broadcast` into an error. However, because the way errors are handled in the language, that effectively made all Octave functions that used broadcasting to error.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Particularly useful was the fact that you gave me the terminology I was missing - I tried a few variations when searching for documentation but I didn't chance upon "broadcast".